# issue with one custom ToggleClass() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
</style>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ToggleClass();">Toggle class</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ToggleClass()
{        
    if($(this).hasClass("bold"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("bold");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("bold");
    }
}
</script>
```

Question:

I made one function: `ToggleClass`, but it does not work, what is the problem?

Comment: why don't use the utility function [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) provided by jQuery

Comment: `onclick="ToggleClass.call(this)"` :)

Comment: @Jack `onclick="ToggleClass.call(this, event)"` for the completeness. Though if OP is using jQuery it'd be better to use it instead of ugly inline handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is two-fold:

**No explicit binding**

You're using inlined code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ToggleClass();">Toggle class</a>
```

Even though the code inside the `onclick` parameter is run in the right context, the function call gets invoked in the context of `window`, i.e. inside `ToggleClass()`, by default, `this` refers to `window`; it's as if `ToggleClass.call(window)` was written. You can bind the function to another object if you wish:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ToggleClass.call(this);">Toggle class</a>
```

Using `.call()` you bind the current element to the function and it will work as expected.

**Not enough jQuery**

You're not doing things in the *jQuery way*.

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-bold">Toggle class</a>
...
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.toggle-bold').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('bold');
        return false; // prevent navigation to #
    });
});
</script>
```

I've removed the `href="javascript:void(0);"` and the inlined code. Instead, I've added a class to target the anchor; if the link only occurs once inside the document, you may want to consider a unique identifier. The click handler is attached once the document is ready.

To prevent the browser from adding that pesky `#` at the end, I'm returning `false` from the click handler to stop event propagation.

Lastly. instead of `hasClass()`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()` I'm using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to send reference to the calling function

```
 ... onclick="ToggleClass(this);"...


<script type="text/javascript">
function ToggleClass(obj)
{        
    if($(obj).hasClass("bold"))
            $(obj).removeClass("bold");
    else
            $(obj).addClass("bold");
}
```

however i always prefer using click function rather than inline javascript

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ToggleClass">Toggle class</a>

<script>
   $('#ToggleClass').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("bold"))
            $(this).removeClass("bold");
    else
            $(this).addClass("bold");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery` the implementation should be as simple as using the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) utility method:

```
<a href="#" id="toggleme">Toggle class</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($)
{
    $('#toggleme').click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('bold');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an inline `onclick` handler. Your HTML:

```
onclick="ToggleClass();"
```

Is interpreted similarly to:

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    //`this` is available inside the onclick method
    ToggleClass(); //but it is not passed to called functions automatically
}
```

You're just calling a function, hence the `this` reference is not set inside this `ToggleClass` execution. By "not set", I mean in the [ES aspect](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3): entering function code with an undefined `this` means that the `this` reference will point to the `window` object, or `undefined` when in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

One way to set the `this` reference for a function execution context is using [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
onclick="ToggleClass.call(this, event);"
```

Read more about the `this` keyword [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

*`event` is not necessary with your code, but event handlers usually expect to receive an event object hence I'm passing it anyway.

---

However, you're already using jQuery, which sets the `this` reference inside event handlers and wraps the event object to make its methods cross-browser. Hence you can just add a JS hook to your element and attach listeners through jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="js-toggleClass">Toggle class</a>
<script>
$('.js-toggleClass').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('bold');
});
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/frd4g/)

I've replaced your `href="javascript:void(0)"` with the jQuery Event object's [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method as JavaScript does not belong inside `href` attributes, and used the jQuery [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method to simplify your logic as well.

The pros of this is the separation between structure (HTML) and behavior (JS), thus keeping your code much more organized and modularized.

Comment: +1. How can I not like an answer based on the same principles as mine? :)

Comment: Heheh true, looking again it looks like I used your answer as boilerplate (though I had mine 80-90% done by the time yours was posted), well mine just has a bit more emphasis on the "why" part and the usual extra almost-unrelated stuff that I put in most answers.

Answer (score -2):

Send current object in `toggleClass()` function like this :

```
ToggleClass(this)
```

Toggle class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ToggleClass(abc)
{        
        if($(abc).hasClass("bold"))
                $(abc).removeClass("bold");
        else
                $(abc).addClass("bold");
}
</script>
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: Simply passing an argument when the function doesn't receive any parameters won't really help.

Comment: It should be either `ToggleClass.call(this)` or like bipen's first snippet.

Comment: yeh like Bipen first script : because we need to current object of element and this is refer to current object.So we need to send object in his parameter.Thanks

Comment: Yes man, re-read my first comment. Just because you passed `this` as argument, your function's `this` won't be magically set to it. Your function should have a parameter to receive the element reference and use that parameter along the code instead of `this` (see bipen's snippet).

Comment: I copied you script to show you that whats the problem in your code.now edited in my code.Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You are calling function ToggleClass(), but yoy are not passing parameter when calling ToggleClass() function , Pass Reference when calling ToggleClass(), otherwise buildin function exists in JQuery.